# file_get_contents() gets 403 from api.github.com every time

Tags: php, github-api

I call myself an experienced PHP developer, but this is one drives me crazy. I'm trying to get release informations of a repository for displaying update-warnings, but I keep returning 403 errors. For simplifying it I used the most simple usage of GitHubs API: GET https://api.github.com/zen. It is kind of a hello world.

This works

- directly in the browser
- with a plain `curl https://api.github.com/zen` in a terminal
- with a PHP-Github-API-Class like [php-github-api](https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api)

This works not

- with a simple `file_get_contents()`from a PHP-Skript

This is my whole simplified code:

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/zen");
    var_dump($content);
?>
```

The browser shows `Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.github.com/zen): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden`, the variable `$content` is a boolean and `false`.

I guess I'm missing some sort of http-header-fields, but neither can I find those informations in the [API-Docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/), nor uses my terminal `curl`-call any special header files and works.

Comment: Did you try using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to compare the different calls?

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled?

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is enabled. Thanks @RickS for the tool recommendation, I will include that in my future workflows. The solution was a missing header field, as I guessed. See marked answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This happens because GitHub requires you to send UserAgent header. It doesn't need to be anything specific. This will do:

```
$opts = [
        'http' => [
                'method' => 'GET',
                'header' => [
                        'User-Agent: PHP'
                ]
        ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$content = file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/zen", false, $context);
var_dump($content);
```

The output is:

```
string(35) "Approachable is better than simple."
```

Comment: That one helped, thanks. Do you know that from experience or is there any instruction in the docs I have overseen?

Comment: FYI. https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required >All API requests MUST include a valid User-Agent header. Requests with no User-Agent header will be rejected. We request that you use your GitHub username, or the name of your application, for the User-Agent header value. This allows us to contact you if there are problems.

Comment: Awesome! I found a lot on `allow_url_fopen` but mine was already on. This was the problem. I also learned about the nifty zen api URL. Thank you!