# GitHub API commits

Tags: php, json, github-api

Do someone here know how to use GitHub API?
I'm trying to make a table retrieving all repositories commits (https://api.github.com/repos/RubeVi/Fenix/commits). Only want to show the sha, but looks like my code is wrong

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/RubeVi/Fenix/commits");
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
?>
<table>
<?php foreach ($obj as $o) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $o["sha"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $o["commit"]["author"]["name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $o["commit"]["author"]["email"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $o["commit"]["message"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Tag things correctly.

Comment: …because you have the wrong URL in your code?

Comment: @duskwuff A lot of things happened dude...

Comment: @duskwuff its complicated

Comment: @Ruben Please don't replace the code in your question with the fixed code! It makes the question make no sense.

Comment: It isnt answered, it need `$opts = ['http' => ['method' => 'GET', 'header' => ['User-Agent: PHP']]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are expecting?

[image: preview]

If so, do it this way, it is easier to see as well:

```
<?php
$opts = ['http' => ['method' => 'GET', 'header' => ['User-Agent: PHP']]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/repos/RubeVi/Fenix/commits", false, $context);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
?>
<table>
<?php foreach ($obj as $o) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $o["sha"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $o["commit"]["author"]["name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $o["commit"]["author"]["email"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $o["commit"]["message"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Fixed the issue using: [file_get_contents() gets 403 from api.github.com everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141315)